# Different Densities in the equation of Continuity, how?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, density, aerodynamics

I'm studying the equation of Continuity from the book Intro to Flight by J. Anderson and there it mentions that

$$\rho_1A_1V_1 = \rho_2A_2V_2$$

If the fluid is assumed to me ideal why does the formula mention different densities at point **A** and point **B**? Shouldn't the density of the fluid remain constant throughout, therefore giving the formula:
$$A_1V_1=A_2V_2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\rho_1A_1V_1=\rho_2A_2V_2$ is used when the fluid is compressible, i.e., density at different points of fluid can also be different. In contrast, $A_1V_1=A_2V_2$ is used when the fluid is incompressible, i.e., its density is constant for every point in the fluid.

Comment: So the ability of a fluid to allow compression or not dictates the use of 'rho' or not. Right?

Comment: @VishwasSharma You can use the former equation for all fluid but if the fluid doesn’t allow compression, the term $\rho$ will cancel out yielding the latter equation.